# Wave from the piezoelectric material is not what I expected. Did I miss a step?

Tags: oscilloscope

The wave from the piezoelectric material may be

1. sine wave (classmate told me )
2. AC wave (but not sine, I suppose it from the paper)
3. DC wave (from the oscilloscope it seems like a DC wave, not AC wave)

Steps:

Red oscilloscope line connects to the red line. Black oscilloscope line connects to the black line. No load (resistor or capacitor), as in the picture shown below

[image: (貼照片)]

Here are the wave situations, shown in the oscilloscope

1. *no press:* a horizontal wave which has noise
2. *at the time I press:* the horizontal wave goes down
3. *at the time i release:* the horizontal wave goes up

After that, the horizontal wave returns back to the original, and this is the reason: I think the wave produced from the piezoelectric material is a DC wave, because there is no AC wave, only DC. However, I read some papers and articles from the internet, and they all said that the wave from the piezoelectric material is definitely not a DC wave. So, did I miss any steps before I tested the wave with the oscilloscope<sup>1</sup>?

I saw a waveform from [this pdf](http://www.shs.edu.tw/works/essay/2014/11/2014111509151611.pdf) ( Chinese version), and in Fig 14 & 15 there is a voltage waveform, as shown below.

[image]

<sup>1</sup>I’m using a WaveRunner-8000 oscilloscope.

Comment: hold it down longer. You may be using 1M input load. The time it takes to drop 64% is the capacitance in uF.  DC is not a wave.

Comment: DC is displayed as a straight line that does **not** move up or down .... any motion in vertical direction, even if it is slow, means that there is a signal

Comment: `not the same as i know` ... you did not say what it is that you know ... how is your observation different from what you know?

Comment: @jsotola as i know,the wave is not the DC wave

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 This time,i press it longer,but only the second i press,the wave goes up horizontally,and than back to the original,i didn't see any AC

Comment: AC down and up is an alternating, bipolar signal. What you need to know is AC is often referred to as 50 or 60 Hz and air conditioning but anything that is a wave or a pulse and returns to 0 is a wave with AC content only.

Comment: Just what are you expecting in terms of a waveform or response to pressure? We do not have much to go by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signal is AC, it goes positive and negative, the frequency is the frequency that you press it.

This piezo disk device is a [transducer](http://en.wikipedia.org/transducer) it converts flexing into the movement of electric charge, flex it one way and charge is pushed into the wires allow it to relax and the charge is pulled back the other way.

Comment: What is "this device"? piezoelectric material?

Comment: This time,i press it longer,but only the second i press,the wave goes up horizontally,and than back to the original,i didn't see any AC

Comment: That's AC. It doesn't give you a static signal proportional to pressure.

Comment: oh~i see ,thx !!

Comment: @Janka I add a picture in my question,and my wave is not like that,static signal

Comment: @Jasen I add a picture in my question,and my wave is not like that

Comment: @electroniccomponent if you imagine position,x, velocity,v and acceleration,a of your finger the signal is close to matching ,a but only with AC part, no DC  ( so we say high pass filtered )

Comment: In fact,I just want to know why can he see that "static signal"by using falling steel ball.Theoretically,our wave should be similar,because the second  that steel ball impact the piezoelectric material should be the same as i press the piezoelectric material